# Laurent series of an even function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose f is even, that is $f(-z) = f(z), z \in \mathbb{C}$ and f has the representation $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$. Since $f(z) = f(-z)$ is the representation of $f(-z)$  given by $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(-z-z_0)^n$ or $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(-z-(-z_0))^n$?

Comment: You do not need $f$ even to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

$z_0$ is a constant, so it's the first one.